# ParameterDecorator that adapts to whether a parameter is optional or not

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

Note: I'm doing this in the context of NestJS, and welcome any answers that leverage it, but this is a more general question about ParameterDecorators, as nest is just building a ParameterDecorator type.

Let's say I have a ParameterDecorator @ParseIt that I invoke as such

```
function func(@ParseIt() arg: CustomType) { ... }
```

so @ParseIt takes whatever the original arg is and parses it into a CustomType. I have this workign without issue. What I can't seem to support is the following

```
function func(@ParseIt() arg: CustomType) { ... }
function func2(@ParseIt() arg?: CustomType) { ... }
```

where ParseIt works like you'd expect. I can get it to either work where it always functions as `string | undefined -> CustomType | undefined`, or `string -> CustomType`, but not where it depends on the optionality of the argument it is modifying

Is this possible in typescript? I figure it probably is possible with typescript 5's powerful decorators, but I don't know them well enough to say. I thought about making ParseIt just always go from `string | undefined -> CustomType | undefined`, so in the case of

```
function func(@ParseIt() arg: CustomType) { ... }
```

the type signature would "protect" us from the fact that underneath the covers, the parse could support undefined...but I'm worried that this could open us up to potential errors (this is where NestJS comes into play, because when you're defining a route and its methods, the ultimate invocation over the network isn't typed, that is to say, if they don't pass in arg, even if you required it, it will invoke the method, and it'd be up to ParseIt to fail out). Ideally I want the ParseIt function to error out in this case, but *not* in the case of `arg?`. Not sure if that is possible without two separate decorators, though

Comment: The new decorators proposal doesn't support parameter decorators anyway. Also, they've never been supported on functions, more's the pity.

Comment: Ah, so is this in fact not possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#differences-with-experimental-legacy-decorators. It's a very frustrating limitation. I found parameter decorators useful for validation and sometimes adapters. It just reaffirms my feeling that ES classes are an awkward feature with awful ergonomics. The TC39 Maximally Minimal doctrine is flawed.

Comment: In TypeScript decorators work based on their predefined behavior and they don't adapt dynamically depending on where they are used. This means that a decorator can't automatically change its behaviour based on whether the parameter it's applied to is optional or not. However you can still make it work the way you want by making some changes in your design.

Comment: @AztecCodes I would love any suggestions for a changed design that would support this, if you have ideas!